# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on boolean on line 22

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Please I need help with this error, gurus in the house.

Its my first php project and the error is giving me a bad day.

It keeps on showing me this;

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\myfirstfile.php on line 22

```
 <?php 

 $query = "SELECT * FROM chat ORDER BY id"; 

 $run = $con->query($query); 

/*22*/ while($row = $run->fetch_array()) :

 ?>

 <div id="chat_data"> 
 <span style="color:green;"><?php echo $row['Nickname']; ?> :</span> 
 <span style="color:brown;"><?php echo $row['text']; ?>:</span> 

 </div>

 <?php
      endwhile;
   ?>
```

Comment: @Aqueous did you check my answer? Please accept it if it's correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The result of your query was false (which means - something went wrong there) so what you are actually doing is `false->fetch_array()`, which doesn't really makes any sense.

If you add some error checking, for example:

```
$run = $con->query($query) or die("Last error: {$con->error}\n");
```

You can see what went wrong there and fix it.

Answer (score -1):

change your fetch statement to

```
$row = $con->fetch_array($run)
```

Comment: The fetch statement is not relevant at all here. check my answer.